# Find $f^TBf$ given $f^TA^TBAf$

Tags: matrices, parameter-estimation

$f$ is an unknown column vector and $A,B$ are square matrices.
Let $x_1 = f^TBf$ and $x_2=f^TA^TBAf$.

Is there a way to estimate somehow $x_1$ given $x_2$, $A$ and $B$?

Will it be possible if a large number of such $x^j_1,x^j_2$ were available, where $j$ denotes the index and each such pair corresponds to a different and known $B_j$?

Edit: A is invertible (or at least has a pseudo inverse).

Thanks.

Comment: No. E.g. when $A=0$, the quantity $x_2$ is always zero.

Comment: Right. I edited.